# Unable to assign value to variable using async function on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I was trying to get jwtauthtoken from user and passing it to a getuserId() which was imported in that js file. But i was getting undefined value instead of decoded id that was returned by the function.

In the getUserId() it displays the decoded token

My console output:

user id 5f68efb234a7656

On get request : undefined

Anyone can help to me resolve the problem.

personalDetailsController.js

```
module.exports.personaldetail_get = async (req,res) => {

    const token = req.cookies.jwtauthtoken;

        let userId = await getUserId(token);
        console.log("On get request : "+ userId); // output On get request : undefined

    res.render('Candidate/personal', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });

}
```

getUserId.js

```
module.exports.getUserId =  (tokenid) => {

    const token = tokenid;

    try{

        if (token) {

            jwt.verify(token,'2308199919990823', async (err, decodedToken) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return null;
                } else {
                    console.log("user id " + decodedToken.id); // Output user id 5f68efb234a7656
                    return decodedToken.id;
                }

            });
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err)
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, you forgot to add ```return``` at the function call ```jwt.verify```...

Comment: `if (token)` the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I tried but now also it returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const decodedToken = await getUserId(token)` means two things :

- getUserId must return a Promise.
- `decodedToken` is given by the *resolution* of this Promise.

```
getUserId = tokenid => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        jwt.verify(tokenid, '2308199919990823', (err, decodedToken) => resolve(decodedToken))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the add a `return` on your function call...

Also the try catch block you have will not work since your verify function is asynchronous...you need to wrap this in a Promise...

```
module.exports.getUserId =  (tokenid) => {

    const token = tokenid;

    if (token) {
        return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
            jwt.verify(token,'2308199919990823', async (err, decodedToken) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return null;
                } else {
                    console.log("user id " + decodedToken.id); // Output user id 5f68efb234a7656
                    return resolve(decodedToken.id);
                }

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only return `jwt.verify` which is an asynchronous function. It will not return the value of the token, which is the expected _result_. Downvoted

Comment: Yeah sorry, i had just realized that this needs to be wrapped in a Promise for it to work properly

Comment: Made the edit, please check and verify...it should return a Promise of a token...thanks

Comment: Fair enough, canceled my downvote. But you should `reject()` instead of `return null`.